# Custom control work in "pages" but "Unknown server tag" in "web part pages"

Tags: web-part-page, web-part-pages, custom-control

I am new to SharePoint even ASP.NET.

I wrote a custom calendar control which inherits the asp:calendar and overrides some function, and it work in blank pages.
But today while I am trying to use the control in a web part page, it shows unknown server tag.

In both page,

> < %@ Register Assembly="SharepointTest,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=846d0a16c362cfbd" 
>   Namespace="SharepointTest" TagPrefix="CC" %>

and the tag

> < CC:EventCalendar runat="server" >< /CC:EventCalendar >

In web.config,

> < SafeControl Assembly="SharepointTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=846d0a16c362cfbd" Namespace="SharepointTest" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />

Did I did anything wrong or miss anything?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to web part pages, things work a bit differently. What I always do and I know it's not the safest, but it's the only way that works for me, is to declare the control in the controls section in your web.config:

```
 <controls>
        <add src="/_controltemplates/ControlName.ascx" tagName="MyTagName" tagPrefix="MyTagPrefix" />
</controls>
```

Comment: Thank you! It is working on the pages now. But still showing error on spd. But I think its good enough for me now.=]

Comment: Yeah, SPD is another trick to get it working.. Glad it helped